# Adding dynamic class name to list of hard coded classes in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I have an element with a list of classes e.g.

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3">Content</div>
```

And I want to add this react variable to the list of classes:

```
{this.state.active ? ' is-active': null}
```

How would I go about adding it into the list, something like this?

```
<div class={{this.state.active ? ' is-active': null} + " class1 class2 class3"}>Content</div>
```

I'm having no luck at all... I'm also kinda new to react :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do the following using template strings:

```
<div className={`${this.state.active ? 'is-active': ''} class1 class2 class3`}>Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work but it's not very good coding

you can do this like this

```
<div class={{this.state.active ? " class1 class2 class3 is-active": "class1 class2 class3"}}>Content</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway that is better practice then?

Comment: yeah the answer down is better coding