# React - Add class along with Dynamic class

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React button that toggles a class name on and off.

But how can I add other classes like

```
<div className={this.state.active ? this.state.feature : null} "another-class">
```

I could add them instead of null but I want the class on top of the toggle class

```
export default class Feature extends React.Component {

  state = {
    feature: this.props.otf,
    active: false,
  }

  toggleClass = () => {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="feature">
        <button onClick={this.toggleClass} ></button>

        <div className={this.state.active ? this.state.feature : null} >

        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding dynamic class name to list of hard coded classes in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283156/adding-dynamic-class-name-to-list-of-hard-coded-classes-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<div className={`${this.state.active ? 'is-active': ''} class1 class2 class3`}>Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<div className={"another-class " + (this.state.active ? this.state.feature : "")} >
```

You can move the `"another-class"` anywhere(LHS or RHS)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this method.

```
render() {
    let button_name = "class";
    if(this.state.active) {
       button_name = "active class";
    }
    return (
      <div className="feature">
        <button onClick={this.toggleClass} ></button>
        <div className={button_name} >
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```